What creates mail count message?
I'm running several Raspberry Pi and when I open a terminal, the message "No mail." is displayed. Email on these Pis is configured to use $HOME/Maildir. If I run the messages program in mailutils, an accurate count of new messages is shown.
I'm using exim4 for email.
After prepping many of the system directories and $HOME, I can't find anything creating the "No mail." message.
What program or script creates this? I'd like to turn it off.

If the message is "You have no mail" then perhaps remove any files in /var/mail - or configure "pam_mail" - but "No mail" - no idea what's producing that
